# How to stop page refresh on form submit, after clicking the OK in ALERT on JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, php, html

If the second **if statement** is true the page will alert and then if I click the ok, the page will start refreshing.

I want to have alert without getting refresh.

PS: If you have any questions in my question, comment down below.

HERE's The structure:

index.php

```
<form action="step2server.php" method="post">
        <div class="inputs">

            <label class ="ccheckin">Check IN:</label>
            <input  class ="ccheckint" name="text_in" id="datetime" required>

            <label class ="ccheckout">Check OUT:</label>
            <input  class ="ccheckoutt" name="text_out" id="datetime1" required>


            <button class="btn" name="submit" id="btn">Reserve</button>
        </div>
        </form>
```

step2server.php

```
//if submit is clicked
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $row = mysqli_fetch_array($reservation))
    {   
        if(!empty($_POST['text_in']) && !empty($_POST['text_out']))
        {
        $checkin = $_POST['text_in'];
        $checkout = $_POST['text_out'];
        $reservation1 = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * from reservation where reservefrom='$checkin' AND reserveto ='$checkout'");     
            if(mysqli_num_rows($reservation1)) 
            {
                echo "<script>alert('Correct'); window.location.replace('reservestep2.php');</script>";
            }
            else
            {
            echo "Wrong";
      }
    }
   }
```

Comment: Search for AJAX and preventDefault

Comment: Why do you need javascript to display a "Correct" text. Can't you just display the text some where in the page?

Answer (score 0):

If your `<input>` type is submit. The page will refresh when you click that, which mean send `GET/POST` request to the server.

If you want to get data without refresh the page. Try using `AJAX` to perform `GET/POST` request and receive data from server instead of normal submit